# setting a variable/ marker to use in a php function in the same php file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, user-input

i want to set a marker like variable which will be set in a particular page and used for validation in common functions. i tried $REQUEST but its not working. Any suggestion? also not able to read input hidden value..
in `php` section

```
<?php $GLOBALS['isRayaPromo'] = "rtrtr"; 
get_template_part('includingFilewithFunctionHere'); 
?>
 <div class="btn_photo_wrapper">
  code here invoking above function
</div>
```

---

say m having function A to called on click of a button. Function A is a common function used in different page flows. But for my page i need to do a specific change in Function A. Which is why i need a marker in my php so tahat the function does the change only for my page based on this marker validation. 
also tried with regular php variable.
cannot pass teh variable in function call as it is a common function which is already being used in other flows and i cannot change the signature of teh function.
 I am a beginner so plz suggest

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.  What is your validation for?

Comment: say m having function A to called on click of a button. Function A is a common function used in different page flows. But for my page i need to do a specific change in Function A. Which is why i need a marker in my php so tahat the function does the change only for my page based on this marker validation.

Comment: Please don't post information asked for in comments. Instead add it to your question as it is a lot easier to read. Also, it means new people can just read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note:

1. You are using `globals`. This is deprecated and strongly discouraged.
2. You forgot the `_` in `$_REQUEST`
3. It's better to use constants instead

An example:

```
define('SOMEVAR', 'I want to use this string e----ve---ry---whereeeee');

function stupidFunction()
{
    echo SOMEVAR;
}
```

You can also just pass variables to functions:

```
$var = "Some stupid text";

function doSomethingAwesome($var)
{
    echo $var;
}
```

### Edit

In order to do what you want, you need to pass by reference. Take a look at the following sample code and take a close look at the `&` that I am using in the function. The `&` sign means that the variable that I pass into the function will not only change in the function scope but in the global scope as well.

```
define('PROMORAYA', '1');

var_dump(PROMORAYA); // Returns string(1) "1"

$isPromo = 0;

whoopdidooptidoo($isPromo);

function whoopdidooptidoo(&$isPromo)
{
    if (PROMORAYA == '1') {
        $isPromo = 1;
    }
}

var_dump($isPromo); // int(1)
```

Comment: i set define('PROMORAYA', '1'); but in function when i read PROMORAYA it gets value 0

Comment: $isRayaPhoto= 0; // set to 1 if it is raya promo
  if (PROMORAYA == '1'){
   $isRayaPhoto= 1;
   echo "hello";
  }
end result isRayaPhoto is displaying 0

Comment: since whoopdidooptidoo() is a common function here... i cannot change its signature or pass any new parameter(here &$isPromo)... which is why i want something to access directly in my function.

Comment: If you can change the contents, you can change the parameters as well. To prevent errors you could set a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `constants` if value to be used is fixed like this.

```
<?php
define("isRayaPromo", "rtrtr");
get_template_part('includingFunctionHere'); 
?>
<div class="btn_photo_wrapper">
  <?php echo isRayaPromo;?>
</div>
```

Comment: i set 
define('PROMORAYA', '1');
but in function when i read PROMORAYA it gets value 0

Comment: $isRayaPhoto= 0; // set to 1 if it is raya promo if (PROMORAYA == '1'){ $isRayaPhoto= 1; echo "hello"; } end result isRayaPhoto is displaying 0

Comment: <?php
define(PROMORAYA, 1); 
$isRayaPhoto= 0;
//get_template_part('includingFunctionHere'); 
?>
<div class="btn_photo_wrapper">
   <?php if(PROMORAYA == 1){
    $isRayaPhoto= 1; echo "hello"; } ?>
</div>
<?php echo $isRayaPhoto ?>  use this